# Which python version should I use for machine learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am totally new to machine learning, after going through many tutorials I am bit confused over which python version is most stable for libraries like tensorflow and keras ?

Some are suggesting python 3.7 while some are telling to use latest one. Which one should I use, any suggestions? Please help!

Comment: I have used both Anaconda, Python 3.9, and Python 3.10 for my ML projects and can't tell much difference between them. As you are a beginner, I don't think the version of python would cause you any trouble.

Comment: I think there's no such big difference between the latest python version and the version 3.7 according to the use of machine learning frameworks and libraries. The latest version may have some improvements and new language features. That's it. I would use the latest python version.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Any Python 3.x will do. Most important is to start.

Comment: Whichever the latest recommended version is for the library you're trying to use. Which is ideally always *the latest Python version available.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

anywhere from Python 3.6–3.9 should work fine, the version doesn't differ too much.

Comment: python 3.10 or greater won't work?